# Heroku application with custom domain doesn't load sll

Tags: node.js, heroku, hosting

I have heroku web application that has custom domain to it, but when you try enter the web with custom domain, it loads SSL cert that was issued for *.herokuapp.com.

I refreshed the cert after adding custom domain.

Note: I added the domain just an hour ago, I know SSL certificates might take some time before changing, but time is pushing us, so I wanted to check if there might be some other causes for this, or if it happened to anybody.

Note 2: DNS works, as well as when you try to access the web with herokuapp.com

Okay update: I used heroku cli to check what domain is SLL issued to, it is the custom one, so it is now only a matter of time, till it will start working right ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It can take up to 24 hours for DNS to fully propagate. You'll need to be sure that you've [configured your DNS correctly](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/custom-domains) in addition to configuring your custom domain on Heroku.